# Help with Controller Extension for Save Redirect Function

Tags: visualforce, controller, extension

I need help creating a controller extension for a Visualforce page. The extension should cause the Save button to redirect to a visual force page named "ProductSelector".

The relevant portion of my VF page code is as follows:

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote__c">
<apex:sectionHeader title="Quote__c Edit" subtitle="{!Quote__c.name}"/>
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="Quote__c Edit" mode="edit">

<apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" id="savebutton"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>

<apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" id="savebutton"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

Comment: you can return the product selector page url from save method.. u need to use custom extension for save functionality

Comment: Yea, I get that I need a custom extension. I am new to this and I am trying to follow a tutorial, but cannot figure it out. I think if I saw an example of an extension using my page, I would have a better idea of where everything goes vs trying to piece it together from the tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add a reference to your extension class like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote__c" extensions="MyExtension">
```

and then that class should follow this pattern:

```
public with sharing class MyExtension {

    public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
    }

    public PageReference save() {
        // Parameters could be added here for the following page
        return Page.ProductSelector;
    }
}
```

resulting in the `save` method taking priority over the default (`StandardController`) one.

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was making it harder than it should be.